# Sort ZipArchive by FullName VB.net

Tags: vb.net, sorting, zip

I'm working with ZIP Files and I'm using the following code:

```
Dim archive As ZipArchive

archive = ZipFile.OpenRead(Filelocation)

Do While (stopLoop)
    entry = archive.Entries.Item(counter)

    If (entry.FullName.Contains(".jpeg") Or entry.FullName.Contains(".jpg") Or entry.FullName.Contains(".png")) Then
        stopLoop = False
    Else
        counter += 1
    End If
Loop
```

These zip files contain images and documents but the images are in a specific order. The user can flip through the images and sometimes my code works perfectly fine (images show 1 throught 10) but other times, the order is completely garbage (images show 2,9,3,7,8....). I understand that the entries are based on when they were added into the archive but is there anyway to sort these by fullname?

Comment: Without having tested, I would assume something like `For Each entry In archive.Entries.OrderBy(Function(e) e.FullName)` would work.  That's got nothing to do with the archive.  It's just how you order enumerable lists in VB.NET.

Comment: Thank you so much! I was trying to figure out how the "OrderBy" worked and I could not figure it out. I already tested the code and made a slight change (e to archive) but it's working beautifully.

Comment: Why would you change `e` to `archive` when it refers to an entry rather than an archive?  I tend to use the first letter(s) of the type name because it's indicative enough for such a localised bit of code and it allows you to use the full name elsewhere, as I have done with `entry` in this code.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Perhaps it's in an event handler with the automtically generated `e as EventArgs`, which I always find a mild nuisance when wanting to use my own variable `e`.

Comment: @AndrewMorton, good point.  `e` may not be an option, unless you change the event handler parameter name, but `archive` would not be an appropriate choice.